# Curl iteratively pass multiple payloads from json or array

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

How do I pass multidimensional associative array or a json as a payload to cURL request. I have been trying to wrap my head around this for sometime now without any success.

Here is what I have done so far. I make a curl request and pass a json to the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` fields. This works alright. The problem is I want the code to run for multiple users which are in a json string saved in a variable

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://test.url/tokens',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "customerName": "orland",
        "mno": "Network",
        "amount": "1",
        "msisdn": "447911123456",
        "description": "Awaiting",
        "reference": "0fgdufgdfgdfs" 
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

The above code works fine.

But the payload for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is not fixed.
So this is what I tried doing, I encoded the json string and tried passing it to a for loop. I am sure the approach isn't bad, but I am not getting the syntax quite right. Here is my code.

```
<?php
$recip = '[{
        "customerName": "Sorland",
        "mno": "Network",
        "amount": "1",
        "msisdn": "447911123346",
        "description": "Awaiting",
        "reference": "0fgdufgdfgdfs" 
    },
    {
        "customerName": "Corland",
        "mno": "MTN",
        "amount": 1,
        "msisdn": "447911123678",
        "description": "Awaiting",
        "reference": "0jsbfbsubfhbj" 
    },
    {
        "customerName": "orland",
        "mno": "MTN",
        "amount": 1,
        "msisdn": "447911123111",
        "description": "Awaiting",
        "reference": "1234568djnfjnfjds" 
}]';

    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => 'https://test.url.com/api/',
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>
    echo ("'{<br>");
    foreach($arr[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {

        echo implode($key . " : " . $value . ",<br>");
    }
    echo "}',<br>";
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
}
```

I want to use a for loop to make multiple curl request with different payloads, and the payloads are coming from the json data above. I converted the json to an array to be able to loop through and converted it back to a json for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: Why are you taking a JSON String, converting it to a PHP Array .,.... only to convert it back to a JSON String... Or am I missing something

Comment: Ok, I get you @RiggsFolly . I was following some tutorials and ended up with that. Please how would you suggest I proceed?

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do, but adding all 4 oth those arrays into on JSON data structure would make it invalid json

Comment: Ok, if you are not sure of what I am trying to achieve then maybe I should rephrase the question. My first code makes a curl call with a payload. I am just trying to making a curl call multiple times. But the payload will come from a json.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I have just edited the question. I hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

This seems a simpler way to make multiple call to curl and save the responses, hope I got the right end of the stick this time :)

```
$recip = 
    '[
        {"customerName": "Sorland", "mno": "Network", "amount": "1",
        "msisdn": "447911123346","description": "Awaiting","reference": "0fgdufgdfgdfs" 
        },
        {"customerName": "Corland","mno": "MTN","amount": 1,
         "msisdn": "447911123678","description": "Awaiting","reference": "0jsbfbsubfhbj" 
        },
        {"customerName": "orland","mno": "MTN","amount": 1,"msisdn": "447911123111",
         "description": "Awaiting","reference": "1234568djnfjnfjds" 
        }
    ]';


// make a PHP datatype out of the JSON so you can use it

$recipients = json_decode($recip);

$responses = [];

foreach ( $recipients as $r) {
   
    $curl = curl_init();
    // convert $r back to json so it can be passed as param
    $postfield = json_encode($r);
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://test.url.com/api/',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfield,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json')
    ));

    $response[] = curl_exec($curl);
    // if you need to know which customer the response was for 
    // use this next line instead, for example
    //$response[$r->customerName] = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
}

// this is now an array of all responses
print_r($responses);
```